# Old perspective map trying to georeference and use with x,y.z tile layers like from Google and OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 3.28 on Linux (Mint 20)

I have a very old map that is a perspective drawing that I would like to overlay current maps like google hybrid onto. I'd like to keep the perspective of the original.

I have added a lot of georeference coordinates to the raster file of this old map. When I run georeference it runs but ultimately I get a cannot create output file error whatever also I select. I've tried changing output filenames, checking or unchecking set resolution.

I wonder if I have to flatten the perspective drawing first so the streets cross at right angles, etc. with a photo editor or maybe with QGIS itself and then georeference.

I've used georeferencing a little bit in the past, but it was always just with flat ortho type raster image.

Can anyone provide any insight, suggestions?

Comment: No need to flatten. I just georeferenced [this perspective image of London](https://www.dreamstime.com/aerial-top-view-city-map-london-black-white-detailed-plan-urban-grid-perspective-vector-illustration-image162566119) to OSM streets and [it output ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5T1H.jpg). So I suggest you add more detail to your question about what exactly you did.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did notice that I had a setting somewhere for the wrong coordinate system. I also couldn't find the enter coordinates from a map option. I wrote them down by hand and entered them that way.

Comment: Did it again with right coordinates & found enter w/map & it worked. I figured since I was using a projection the projection would work the best, it  didn't. Poly 2 was the best. This plate slice failed altogether.

Comment: So I now have the old map warped to fit the base maps. Is there a way to reverse the process and get all the layers into the projection of the original old perspective map?  I figure I'd have to limit the extent